# Django rest framework - get all user data when login

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to get all the user data for the user while login in a single response like this:

```
{   "email": "email@user.com",   
     "tokens": {"access": "ACCESSTOKEN", }, "user_data": {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe"}  }
```

so far I can only get the email and the token.

urls.py

path('login/', LoginAPIView.as_view(), name="login"),

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()
```

serializers.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=3)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=60, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tokens(self, obj):
        user = User.objects.get(email=obj['email'])
        return {
            'access': user.tokens()['access']
        }

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'tokens']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        filtered_user_by_email = User.objects.filter(email=email)

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Account disabled, contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')

        return {
            'email': user.email, 'tokens': user.tokens
        }
```

views.py

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The only thing I manage to do is to add the "first_name" and "last_name" to the Meta class field in serializer, but then I have to provide these fields during the login.

Comment: You might want to look at the serializer's meta field `read_only_fields` and `write_only_fields` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields which will allow you to specify that some fields are only to be read, but not sent on a write request.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks a lot ! But is there a more elegant solution? Can't imagine adding hundreds of items in these fields.

Comment: @Martelius do you have hundreds of fields per model ? you can also create a UserSerializer class then create multiple classes that inherit from it with their own `write_only_fields` and `read_only_fields` then change the serializer class depending on the `request.method` by overriding `get_serializer_class` in the view instead of providing `serializer_class`